# Input "image" does not load form value in new Chrome v69. Post empty

Tags: php, google-chrome

Input "image" does not load form value in Chrome 69.Post empty.
Input "submit" works normally on Chrome 69.

In Chrome 68 or the Opera normally works any input.

What has changed?

```
<input type="image" src="../img/ACCE.png" align="center" name="await" value="await">

<?PHP echo $_POST['await']?>
//Chrome 69 : empty;
//Chrome 68 : await;
//Opera : await;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use input image only when mapping the image. In simple cases, use the button submit.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome changed the behavior for spec-compliance and interoperability.
https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5672688152477696

[HTML specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#image-button-state-(type=image)) also says:

> #### Bookkeeping details
>
> - The element's value attribute must be omitted.