# Submit form with <input type = 'image'> no longer working in Chrome

Tags: php, html, google-chrome

The image button:

```
<form name='form1' method='post' target='new'>
    <input type='image' src='dismiss.png' name='inputname' value='inputvalue'/>
</form>
```

In Chrome 69.0.3497.100, var_dump($_POST) looks like this:

```
array(2) { ["dismiss_x"]=> string(1) "5" ["dismiss_y"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

In FF and Safari, it looks like this (correct with name and value):

```
array(3) { ["dismiss_x"]=> string(1) "5" ["dismiss_y"]=> string(1) "9" ["inputname"]=> string(10) "inputvalue" } dis
```

Chrome seems to be sending only the coordinates of the click, not the actual input name or value.

This worked fine in Chrome last week.

Changing input type to "submit" works fine in Chrome as well.

Comment: Is the form being submitted? If so then you have a server-side problem, nothing to do with the browser.

Comment: Also, ponder for a moment on what would happen if I opened up my web inspector and changed the value of that input to `foo' OR '1'='1` before submitting. Then look up SQL injection...

Comment: This one is the alternate solution. Try using input type="submit". If that works in chrome you can give the styles for input type="submit"

css
.input{
    background-image: url('dismiss.png');
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border: 0;
    cursor: pointer;}

Comment: The form is being submitted, but not with "dismiss". isset comes up blank each time, but only in Chrome. In FF and Safari, isset shows "dismiss".

Comment: I just updated the question. var_dump($_POST) shows two different values when using Chrome vs. Firefox/Safari

Comment: Seems image form submission no longer works in Chrome. Works fine if I change input type to submit. Nothing to do with the SQL or anything like that. Purely just input name / value not being passed along if an image.

Comment: Chrome spec compliance has apparently changed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52299877/input-image-does-not-load-form-value-in-new-chrome-v69-post-empty

Answer (score 6):

Chrome spec compliance apparently has changed:

https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5672688152477696

This accomplishes the exact same thing, and works on all browsers:

```
<form name='form1' method='post' target='new'>
    <button type='submit' name='inputname' value='inputvalue' style='background:none;border:none;padding:0'><img src='dismiss.png'></button>
</form>
```